# Bukkit and Vault: Is there a way to loop through every single player's balance?

Tags: java, bukkit

I am creating a Bukkit plugin where when a command is run, all player's balances will be modified (offline ones, too). I know it would be easy to do this with the online players, and using:

```
economy.withdrawPlayer(<player>, <amount>);
```

by simply looping through the online players, but could I somehow loop through ALL players and modify their account balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bukkit.getOfflinePlayers() to get all Players that have joined a server. Example:

```
for (OfflinePlayer player : Bukkit.getOfflinePlayers()) {
    economy.withdrawPlayer(player, <amount>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Would I have to do a separate loop for online players as well? Also, would I have to make the variable type for 'player' as 'OfflinePlayer'? As Eclipse is telling me to do that.

Comment: Oops, yes my bad - that should be OfflinePlayer instead of Player. Also if you check the JavaDocs for Server#getOfflinePlayers it says that it gets every Player that has joined the server, so you only need to do getOfflinePlayers.